# Haskell Tasty.HUnit : how to run multiple tests with IO

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to run multiple tests (that is, multiple Assertions) within a Test.Tasty testGroup; but feeding in a single "object" that has been read in from IO.

For example, I read & parse a file; and I want to make multiple assertions against the result of that file.  Something like

```
tests :: [String] -> TestTree
tests ls = testGroup "tests" [ testCase "length" $ length ls @?= 2
                             , testCase "foo"    $ ls !! 0 @?= "foo"
                             ]

main = do
  ls :: [String] <- read <$> readFile "/tmp/hunit"
  defaultMain (tests ls)
```

However, the above requires that the IO is performed before calling the tests; and is performed even if only a subset of tests is requested (whether or not that subset actually uses the IO result).

Alternatively, each testCase can perform its own IO (an Assertion is just IO (), after all); but that potentially means IO being performed repeatedly, which is not what I want.

Alternatively again, a testCase can include a `do {}` block which calls multiple assertions; but this will mean that individual tests are not selectable, and won't get verbose output to confirm which tests were run.

`Test.Tasty.withResource` looks hopeful; and if its third argument were `a -> TestTree`, I could work with that; however, it isn't, it's `IO a -> TestTree`, and I'm struggling to work out how to safely extract the `a` to use in my test cases.

I've tried playing with this, but I fear I'm missing something fundamental...

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 3):

You are right looking at the

```
withResource
  :: IO a -- ^ initialize the resource
  -> (a -> IO ()) -- ^ free the resource
  -> (IO a -> TestTree)
    -- ^ @'IO' a@ is an action which returns the acquired resource.
    -- Despite it being an 'IO' action, the resource it returns will be
    -- acquired only once and shared across all the tests in the tree.
  -> TestTree
```

The idea is that you can write your scenario as:

```
tests :: IO String -> TestTree
tests lsIO = testGroup "tests"
    [ testCase "length" $ do
        ls <- lsIO
        length ls @?= 2
    , testCase "foo"    $ do
        ls <- lsIO
        ls !! 0 @?= "foo"
    , testCase "no io" $ do
        return ()
    ]

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain (withResource acquire tests)

acquire :: IO [String]
acquire = read <$> readFile "/tmp/hunit"
```

i.e. it looks like you'd read file multiple times, but `tasty` performs the action only once. That's what the comment says :)
Try adding `putStrLn "trace debug"` to the `acquire` to see for sure, that it's run mostly once (i.e. not run if you only ask for `no io` test).

Comment: Well strike me pink, you're right!  Many thanks @phadej.  I had seen the comment, but it had caused me cognitive dissonance on the first pass and I had somehow blanked on it.

Comment: This example doesn't type check for me. The second argument to `withResource` i.e. `(a -> IO ())` is not given. It would be great if you could improve the answer by adding it.